# How to get value of radio buttons that are separated by divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 radio buttons, while they all share the same `name`, for visual purposes, they're encapsulated in their own `Divs`. The issue is, when I try to retrieve the value of the radio buttons (aka the selected button), it returns an error `ReferenceError: editList is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (sqlTemplate.html:56)`

Here is the code:

```js
   var a;
        
    document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function(){
        a = editList.value;
        console.log(a);
    }
```

```css
#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    width: 150px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

.radioInputStyle{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.radioLabelStyle{
    
}

#radioSubmitButtonDiv{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#submitButton{
    width: 174px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#submitButton:active{
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" style="display: inline;">
           
           <div id="radioGroupContainer">
           
            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="always" class="radioLabelStyle">Linear</label>
                <input id="radButLinear" type="radio" name="editList" value="always" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>   

            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="always" class="radioLabelStyle">Tactile</label>
                <input id="radButTactile" type="radio" name="editList" value="always" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>

            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="always" class="radioLabelStyle">Tactile and Clicky</label>
                <input id="radButTandC" type="radio" name="editList" value="always" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>
            
           </div>
        </form>
        
        <div id="radioSubmitButtonDiv">
            
            <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            
        </div>
```

How can I retrieve the value while keeping them separated?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: What's `editList`?

Comment: You have 2 IDs in each input, delete the second one for each input.

Comment: If you want to avoid the hassle of making up matching `for`/`id` pairs for your label and input, you can make your input a child of label, if you want.

Comment: You have to define `editList`, your function doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.

First of all you are using dual ids on the radio buttons, and the second id is common. So scrap the second id declaration for all.

Then the `for` attribute of the labels should point to the correct remaining `id` of each input.

Then you are using the same `value` for all three radio buttons which will not help you in understanding what the user selected.

Finally in your script there you need to query for the checked radio button `document.querySelector('.radioInputStyle:checked')` before accessing its `value`

So

```js
var a;
        
document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function(){
    a = document.querySelector('.radioInputStyle:checked').value;
    console.log(a);
}
```

```css
#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
    width: 150px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

#radioButtonCol1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 30px;
}

#radioButtonCol1 > *{
    display: block;
}

.radioInputStyle{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.radioLabelStyle{
    
}

#radioSubmitButtonDiv{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#submitButton{
    width: 174px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#submitButton:active{
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" style="display: inline;">
           
           <div id="radioGroupContainer">
           
            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="radButLinear" class="radioLabelStyle">Linear</label>
                <input id="radButLinear" type="radio" name="editList" value="linear" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>   

            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="radButTactile" class="radioLabelStyle">Tactile</label>
                <input id="radButTactile" type="radio" name="editList" value="tactile" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>

            <div id="radioButtonCol1">
                <label for="radButTandC" class="radioLabelStyle">Tactile and Clicky</label>
                <input id="radButTandC" type="radio" name="editList" value="both" class="radioInputStyle"/>
            </div>
            
           </div>
        </form>
        
        <div id="radioSubmitButtonDiv">
            
            <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            
        </div>
```

Comment: Dont you think adding document.querySelector('.radioInputStyle:checked').value is going to pick up all the radio buttons with input style class="radioInputStyle" ? because there might be case where I would be applying the same style for different section in the same page ?

Comment: Yes, in that case you should use `document.querySelector('input[name="editList"]:checked').value`